# Is it possible to use Micronaut Declarative HTTP client in grails 4 functional API tests?

Tags: grails, micronaut

I am trying to create a Declarative client to test the API I am writing in grails 4, like you can do it in micronaut.

As far as I have come, you can create a declarative client if you know the base URL at compile time. Because the grails functional (integration) tests create a server on a random port, you cannot know that port beforehand and use the @Client('http://localhost:8080') annotation.

Using something like  @Client('http://localhost:${local.server.port}') fails with grails complaining that the configuration property cannot be looked up.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I know why `@Client('http://localhost:${local.server.port}') ` doesn't work but I am surprised that it doesn't compile.

Comment: Sorry, it does compile. I will correct the question. I meant complaining, and somehow compiling came out.

Comment: Makes sense.  I think the answers to the question in the title and the question in the body are both "yes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to use Micronnaut Declarative HTTP client in grails 4
> functional API tests?

It is.

A problem with doing that is that when using `@Client('/')` to connect to the local running server, an `EmbeddedServer` bean needs to be configured in the context to answer the question of what port the app is running on.  Some of the relevant code is at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/458bbf07221407abe7e283815fb62b7b4d1fc224/http-client-core/src/main/java/io/micronaut/http/client/DefaultLoadBalancerResolver.java#L93.

We will add testing support to make this easier but you can make it work by registering the bean yourself.  See the following:

- [src/integration-test/groovy/com/objectcomputing/example/TestEmbeddedServer.groovy](https://github.com/puneetbehl/grails-mn-httpclient-demo/blob/f0ab9a31ac587b027ec331c71c0ba888d870a6f2/src/integration-test/groovy/com/objectcomputing/example/TestEmbeddedServer.groovy)
- [src/integration-test/groovy/com/objectcomputing/example/BookClient.groovy](https://github.com/puneetbehl/grails-mn-httpclient-demo/blob/f0ab9a31ac587b027ec331c71c0ba888d870a6f2/src/integration-test/groovy/com/objectcomputing/example/BookClient.groovy)
- [src/integration-test/groovy/com/objectcomputing/example/EmbeddedServerTest.groovy](https://github.com/puneetbehl/grails-mn-httpclient-demo/blob/f0ab9a31ac587b027ec331c71c0ba888d870a6f2/src/integration-test/groovy/com/objectcomputing/example/EmbeddedServerTest.groovy)
- [src/integration-test/groovy/com/objectcomputing/example/BookFunctionalSpec.groovy](https://github.com/puneetbehl/grails-mn-httpclient-demo/blob/f0ab9a31ac587b027ec331c71c0ba888d870a6f2/src/integration-test/groovy/com/objectcomputing/example/BookFunctionalSpec.groovy)

That is a kludge for now, but I believe it will work until proper support is released in the testing framework.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! I will test that and report back.

Comment: Hi, Jeff It seems i am missing some glue here.

How can I add the TestEmbeddedServer to the beanContext?

Placing the @Singleton in the same package does not work, adding it to resources.groovy, doesn't work either.

Comment: Ok, solved that one, I did not use the right Singleton annotation (need to use javax.inject.Singleton).

However now, the TestEmbeddedServer's port is uninitialized. I'll see if I can find how to access the current random server port in Micronaut.

Comment: Fixed it with this addition to TestEmbeddedServer:
int getPort() { Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.webServer.port    }

Comment: "I'll see if I can find how to access the current random server port in Micronaut" -  Tests marked with `@IntegrationTest` automatically have a property named `serverPort` added to them.  That has the value you want.  That is referenced at https://github.com/puneetbehl/grails-mn-httpclient-demo/blob/f0ab9a31ac587b027ec331c71c0ba888d870a6f2/src/integration-test/groovy/com/objectcomputing/example/EmbeddedServerTest.groovy#L14.

Comment: "Placing the @Singleton in the same package does not work" - It does work for me and for lots of apps.  Are you compiling your tests with `testCompile "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-groovy"` like the project I linked in the answer?

Comment: "int getPort() { Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.webServer.port }" - You really shouldn't do that.  You should refer to the `serverPort` property in your `@IntegrationTest` marked class.

Comment: OK, i missed that code in the trait, but it is not working (i guess OnceBefore is not being picked up by Spock).

Comment: I feel that any issues left are probably due to my own project, so I'll mark the response valid, as, at least it took me 99% of the way, if not 100%. Thanks Jeff, like always you're a trove of knowledge.

Comment: Another thing to look for is make sure you are using `javax.inject.Singleton`, not `groovy.lang.Singleton`.

Comment: Yes, that had indeed been my mistake.